# NextJS doesn't send pre-rendered HTML as the page source when using React Context

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, react-context, redux-persist

I am having an issue where I use Context with NextJS. When I see page source, I don't see any pre-rendered HTML.

Now, in the page source I am not able to see any pre-rendered data after this tag -

Here is how I return Components from _app.js currently -

```
<Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
        <InternetConnectionStatusProvider>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        {/* </InternetConnectionStatusProvider> */}
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
```

Context -

```
const { createContext, useState, useEffect, useMemo } = require('react')

export const InternetConnectionStatusContext = createContext({
  isOnline: true,
})

export const InternetConnectionStatusProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isOnline, setOnline] = useState(true)

  // if (typeof navigator === 'undefined') {
  //   return null
  // }

  useEffect(() => {
    setOnline(navigator.onLine)

    window.addEventListener('online', () => {
      setOnline(true)
    })

    window.addEventListener('offline', () => {
      setOnline(false)
    })

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('online', () => {
        setOnline(true)
      })

      window.removeEventListener('offline', () => {
        setOnline(false)
      })
    }
  }, [navigator.onLine])

  const value = useMemo(() => ({ isOnline }))

  return (
    <InternetConnectionStatusContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </InternetConnectionStatusContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Please note there is a similar issue with Redux - Persist and both of these don't work standalone as well.

Expectation is to have NextJS pre-rendering these pages as well.

Comment: I think the PersistGate delays rendering until the store has been hydrated.  Which will be never on SSR.

Comment: Linda - thanks for responding. Yes, that's the reason and is an issue with data persistent in nextjs apps.

Answer (score 2):

To those who are seeing this issue with their apps. It's an issue with hydrating next apps when using a library like redux-persist. Its tendency is to delay the code execution in order to pre-populate state from local storage.

And this delay causes server to send null as a response. It's better to not use this library with nextjs until a fix comes.